# htaccess rewrite to subcategory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Working on a new site and need a rewrite rule when http://www.placewomen.com/new/index.php?var=c/454/700 is shown I would like a rewrite rule to show it as http://www.placewomen.com/c/454/700/.

For now I have this in my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^placewomen.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.placewomen.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*[^/]) /new/index.php?var=$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/placeholder.jpg -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/placeholder.jpg [L]
```

I´m a frontender but my programming skills are.....not so great=! :)
Help is highly appreciated!

greetings,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this rule just below your first `www handler` rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^placewomen.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.placewomen.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+new/index\.php\?var=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /new/index.php?var=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/placeholder.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/placeholder.jpg [L]
```

Comment: Hi, when I use that rewrite it doesn't work like I aspect...the url is rewritten BUT code on /new/index.php isn't executed (creating folder+image when subdirectory doens't exist)...

Comment: because of limited characters in comment I've placed a second answer with comment on your code. You can see it live by pushing F5.

Comment: Is this .htaccess in `/new/` directory or a level above it?

Comment: it´s in the root of website, right now I don´t have a htaccess in /new/ - should I have one there to make this work??

Comment: No its not needed in new. Let it where it is. I am testing your code and will update my answer.

Comment: ok check updated code now. Replace all of your code with this.

Answer (score 0):

because I can't place a big comment on a answer I will try here...
Hi, when I use that rewrite it doesn't work like I aspect...the url is rewritten BUT code on /new/index.php isn't executed (creating folder+image when subdirectory doens't exist). Here's the wanted process: if subdirectory doens't exist goto /new/index.php. If it does exist show the image placeholder.jpg. When a new image is created I don't want to show it as http://www.placewomen.com/new/index.php?var=c/355/676 but http://www.placewomen.com/c/355/676. Your code is now placed like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^placewomen.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.placewomen.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+new/index\.php\?var=([^\s&]+) [NC]

RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*[^/]) /new/index.php?var=$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/placeholder.jpg -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/placeholder.jpg [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

A tricky one:

When http://www.placewomen.com/sub1/sub2/ is called is it possible to show the contents of http://www.placewomen.com/c/sub1/sub2/, so it makes the c gone?

A bit tricky because there is also a check for a empty sub and physically the new url-rewrite doens't exist...